# how to remove equal values at the same row in two columns in a dataframe and store the rest in a new DF without modifying the original DF in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so if column A has at row 2 value = 6
and column B has at the same row =2 the same value =6 remove it.
otherwise store the not equal values at A' and B' in a new dataframe.

not sure if df.drop_duplicates would modify all row at other columns in the original DF

Answer (score 1):

[`drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) works to remove duplicates across **rows**, not columns.

This is different from what you describe: removing rows that have the same value in two columns.

Use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
out = df[df['A'].ne(df['B'])]
```

Example output:

```
   A  B
0  4  2
1  5  4
3  7  8
```

Used input:

```
   A  B
0  4  2
1  5  4
2  6  6
3  7  8
```